# How to detect if method in the class has an argument, that satisfies concept?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

#### What I wanted to do

I really like c++20 concepts. And can I see them as a great tool to replace interfaces + base classes functions with concepts + type erasure.

I had interface for executor. Some class, that accepts other functions and does with them something in derived. For example, runs in another thread, put in the queue or just runs it in place.

```cpp
struct IExecutor {
  using callback_t = std::function<void()>;
  virtual void execute(callback_t callback) = 0;
  virtual ~IExecutor() = default;
};
```

So I tried to replace it with concept, that allows any class that have `operator ()` which accepts any callable, not only `std::function`. May be it is too much and `std::function` would be enough for most use cases, but I wanted to do this anyway.

#### This is what I got

```cpp
using callback_t = std::function<void()>;
using executor_t = std::function<void(callback_t)>;

template<typename...Args>
struct any_invocable_args_t {
    template<std::invocable<Args...> T>
    consteval operator T () const {
        return std::declval<T>();
    }
};

template<typename...Args>
inline static constexpr auto any_invocable_args = any_invocable_args_t<Args...>{};

inline static constexpr auto any_invocable = any_invocable_args_t<>{};

namespace concepts {
    template<typename T>
    concept executor = requires (T ex) {
        { ex(any_invocable) };
    };
}
```

- `callback_t` and `executor_t` are aliases for `std::function` to use as type erased "base classes"
- `any_invocable_args_t` is a type that can't do anything in runtime, because it uses `std::declval` in implementation, but in compile-time it can be used to check if there is or there isn't a valid conversion to anything that is `std::invocable`. This is the trick, that I came up with, wile I was trying to check if argument that accepted by `operator ()` can ba any callable or not. In other words, if the argument satisfies `std::invocable` concept.
- `executor` is a concept, that I tried to make. It should be applicable only to types, that have `operator ()` that accepts all invocables without arguments. Concept for this signature would look like this `(std::invocable auto&& fn)`.

This code works for every types that I tried, but fails if there are more than one overload of `operator ()`, there are more than one implicit conversion.

Here are some examples

```cpp
struct CustomInvocable1 {
    void operator () () {}
};

struct CustomInvocable2 {
    void operator () () {}
};

struct Works1Executor {
    void operator () (std::function<void()>) {}
};

struct Works2Executor {
    void operator () (std::function<void()> const&) {}
};

struct Works3Executor {
    void operator () (CustomInvocable1) {}
};

struct Works4Executor {
    void operator () (auto&&) {}
};

struct DoesntWork1Executor {
    void operator () (CustomInvocable1) {}
    void operator () (CustomInvocable2) {}
};
```

#### Usage examples

```cpp
// Function template that restricted by concepts::executor
id accept_executor(concepts::executor auto ex) {
    // do smth ...
}

void do_smth() {
    { // compiles
        auto ex = Works1Executor{};
        accept_executor(ex);
    }

    { // compiles
        auto ex = Works2Executor{};
        accept_executor(ex);
    }

    { // compiles
        auto ex = Works3Executor{};
        accept_executor(ex);
    }

    { // compiles
        auto ex = Works4Executor{};
        accept_executor(ex);
    }

    { // doesn't compile
      // error: no instance of function template "accept_executor" matches the argument list
        auto ex = DoesntWork1Executor{};
        accept_executor(ex);
    }
}
```

#### Questions

So, the final questions.
Is there a way to make `DoesntWork1Executor` case to compile as well?
Is there more simple and right way to do it? `any_invocable_args_t` trick looks like a c++20 iteration of template hackery.

#### What I tried and it didn't work

It first I tried to something like this as it. The idea is that `std::invocable auto fn` acts like interface. But that doesn't compile.

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept executor = requires (T ex, std::invocable auto&& fn) {
    { ex(std::forward<F>(fn)) };
};
```

Next idea was to add second template argument and restrict it. That compiles, but requires to specify the second argument `F`, which I don't want to do, because I want to be able to specify any callable, not a callable of a certain type.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename F>
concept executor = requires (T ex, F&& fn) {
    requires std::invocable<F>;
    { ex(std::forward<F>(fn)) };
};
```

Comment: What doesn't compile in this case? Could you explain what does DoesntWork1Executor or any of the executor structs get used in? Where do you exactly use the executor concept itself?

Comment: @guacamoleku, sorry for that. I added "Usage examples" block, that illustrates what compiles and what doesn't. This is just an example. Their intended use as any other concepts.

Comment: `DoesntWork1Executor` simply isn't an `executor` - that seems totally correct. It doesn't actually accept any callable, it only accepts these two specific ones. Why would you _want_ to make that case compile?

Comment: `Works3Executor` isn't really an executor either - it's bad that that one compiles. It only accepts one specific kind of callable.

Comment: @Barry, the 'why would I' question is not really important, it's just a toy example. This is more about how to restrict a function argument not to a type, but to a set of types using template and concepts.

Comment: About `Works3Executor`. I'm not really sure how this compiles myself. I'm using Visual Studio 2022. Maybe result compiler dependent.

Comment: @smidimir: "*I see them as a great tool to replace interfaces + base classes functions with concepts + type erasure*" That's not what they're for, and you shouldn't try to use them as such.

Comment: `DoesntWorkExecutor` fails to compile because its two methods are identical and any attempt to call either will be ambiguous. Suffixing either with `const` allows the code to compile.